# What is wrong with my CAS / Tomcat/ SSL Configuration: PKIX path building failed

Tags: tomcat, ssl-certificate, single-sign-on, cas

We are using **CAS** as our *Single Sign On* provider.  Currently, I have it deployed locally, along with the applications which will be participating in *Single Sing On*.  Things work as expected.  For my local environment, I use a self-signed certificate.

We have deployed the cluster of applications to a new server (**DEVSERVER-01**) to facilitate testing.  For this **TEST** environment, we are using a self-signed certificate.  We are getting the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:341)
    org.jasig.cas.client.util.CommonUtils.getResponseFromServer(CommonUtils.java:305)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.retrieveResponseFromServer(AbstractCasProtocolUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:50)
    org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.validate(AbstractUrlBasedTicketValidator.java:207)
    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticateNow(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:140)
    org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(CasAuthenticationProvider.java:126)
    org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(CasAuthenticationFilter.java:242)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
```

**Note**

1. There are three applications deployed to the same Tomcat Instance: CAS + two members.
2. I can correctly see the Login Page when visiting the CAS URL: https://devserver-01.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443/kas
3. I can correctly see the Login Page when visiting the URL for either member application.
4. I only get the above-error when CAS redirects back to a member **after** I log in.

Here is a log (`-Djavax.net.debug=ssl`) showing which `cacert` file the Tomcat Instance is using:

```
2014-01-08 12:11:20 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore
...
adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=DEVSERVER-01.XXX.XXX.XXX, OU=Test, O=Test, L=Test, ST=Test, C=Test
  Issuer:  CN=DEVSERVER-01.XXX.XXX.XXX, OU=Test, O=Test, L=Test, ST=Test, C=Test
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x2aed8ad2
  Valid from Wed Jan 08 12:06:08 EST 2014 until Sun Oct 23 13:06:08 EDT 2287
...
```

---

**Note**

Usually, I would say that the self-signed certificate simply needs to be imported.  However:

```
C:\XXXX\XXXX>keytool -list -v -alias tomcat -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts"
Enter keystore password:
Alias name: tomcat
Creation date: Jan 8, 2014
Entry type: trustedCertEntry

Owner: CN=DEVSERVER-01.XXX.XXX.XXX, OU=Test, O=Test, L=Test, ST=Test, C=Test
Issuer: CN=DEVSERVER-01.XXX.XXX.XXX, OU=Test, O=Test, L=Test, ST=Test, C=Test
Serial number: 2aed8ad2
Valid from: Wed Jan 08 12:06:08 EST 2014 until: Sun Oct 23 13:06:08 EDT 2287
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  B4:51:27:29:9A:5C:43:02:79:05:5F:B9:2E:D8:38:31
         SHA1: B2:A6:BB:02:D1:E2:89:62:FF:54:E2:1F:84:69:36:C9:8B:9D:2C:42
         SHA256: 31:2B:4C:DD:E2:31:CB:89:50:4B:37:D4:4D:D9:28:CC:AF:89:B4:BE:7B:
B5:11:B2:BD:0C:A2:2B:86:24:5F:2A
         Signature algorithm name: SHA256withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: 61 FF C1 97 80 78 4D 81   54 D2 BD CE AD D0 B4 14  a....xM.T.......
0010: DC DB 52 EE                                        ..R.
]
]
```

So...any ideas?

Comment: did you check if any of the redirects has a cert that its not imported?